# Range between Percentages in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, range, formula

Condition:

```
     \<10000 = 0%
```

Between 10000 and 20000 = 5%
Greater than 20000 = 20%

Formula so far:

```
      =IF(B2\>20000,"10%",

       IF(AND(B2\>=10000,B2\<20000,"5%"),

      IF(B2\<10000,"0%")))

       Issue: Excel is not picking up the B2\>=10000,B2\<20000,"5%" portion.
```

Please advise.

No result.

Answer (score 0):

Your "5%" is inside *logical test* part.
Should be:

```
=IF(B2>=20000,"10%",IF(AND(B2>=10000,B2<20000),"5%",IF(B2<10000,"0%")))
```

Also in your formula 20000 returns false as your test is >20000 or <20000, but nowhere =20000 (added it to 10% part - `B2>=20000`)

Comment: Hello, I made the changes:=IF(B2>20000,"10%",IF(AND(B2>=10000,B2<=20000,"5%"),IF(B2<10000,"0%"))) -> but it still returning a FALSE value. I need the percentages. Please advise.

Comment: Because in your formula "5%" is in AND statement again. Should be: =IF(B2>20000,"10%",IF(AND(B2>=10000,B2<=20000),"5%",IF(B2<10000,"0%")))

Comment: It is the same formula - what's difference? Sorry for the questions.

Comment: No it is not. In your formula there is AND(B2>=10000,B2<=20000,"5%") - all 3 parameters are between brackets in AND statement ( AND(1,2,3) ), while it should be only 2 parameters, like in mine: AND(B2>=10000,B2<=20000). "5% is after AND statement

Comment: I see now. It is the placement of the closing ) next to the "5%." Thank-you so much!